# getting the context object after setting it using @ContextConfiguration

Tags: spring, junit

How do I get `ApplicationContext` object so that i can use it in my code, after setting context using`@ContextConfiguration`.

My test class extends `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` extends `AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests`, which has a protected `applicationContext` field. Your test class can just use that.

Answer (score 10):

I generaly just inject a copy of the Application Context into the unit test:

```
 @Autowired 
   ApplicationContext context;
```